# Работа с переменными в Perl

Tags: perl

Надо получить почту и расфасовать ее по txt файликам. У меня есть переменная `$_[0]`, в которой хранится порядковый номер письма. Почему

```
open(FILE "> $_[0]mail.txt")
```

не работает? Название получается mail.txt. Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете устаревший способ работы с файлами. Гораздо лучше так

```
open my $fh, '>', $filename or die "$!: $filename";
print $fh $mail_body;
close $fh
```

Comment: где почитать что это устаревший метод?
желательно на русском.
тут описано 2 метода http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html
и что должно быть в $fh в таком случае?

Answer (score 0):

Вот там где переменная $[0] появляется, присвой ее нормальной переменной с нормально зоной видимости my $var = $[0]
и потом уже где надо open(FILE '>'.$var.'mail.txt')

Answer (score 0):

А напишите перед созданием файла эту строчку и проверьте есть ли у вас что-то в этой переменной:
print $_[0]; exit;

Answer (score 0):

А лучше присваивание сделать так:

```
my $filename = shift;
```

Выглядит лучше :-)

Answer (score 0):

open(FILE "> ${_[0]}mail.txt")